# How can I include parameters in Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a query string to extract data from my master sheet, which looks like this:

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("1ABCsxIDRXU-k6YXWJ47Awjk4757VsMFBmye7rkBC123","Master!$A$1:$H"),"SELECT * **WHERE Col2 = 'abc123'** ORDER by Col1",1)
```

However, the problem is it only extracts data for "abc123" in column 2 of my Master Sheet

I also would like to include data that has parameters behind? For example: *abc123&fbclid=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx*

How can I include both **with and without** parameters data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`=query({K14:M17},"SELECT * WHERE Col2 contains 'abc123'",1)`

`contains` is a substring match. Refer the [documentation on Query](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#where), specifically "WHERE" for more details and alternatives

Comment: It works.
Thanks a lot!